# Is the my cassandra config implement true

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with three nodes under normal circumstances. When I send write request cluster from node.js, I want all nodes to write back to me after writing, while reading, i want to be able to read which node I am connected to. I want this setup to continue when one of the three nodes has died. I chose replication factor= 3 consistency=2 
How should I implement a configuration. Is the config implement true ?
With my respects...

Answer (score 1):

So I unfortunately have no real clue about the provided numbers from the node JS driver, but I know something about the consistency levels, which I suspect you are using in the background, assuming that you are using this driver: http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/.

Just a basic thing: The nodes don't write back to you directly, but your query is sent to one node, the coordinator of that query, which then distributes the query in your cluster according to your consistency level specifications (at least if it's a simple query, more complex destribution logic applies in case of batch queries). The coordinator then reports back to you when the query is executed.

Whether your requirements can be fulfilled at all depends on the replication factor you chose. The problem here is that cassandra only knows so many of them. The options for writing are: all (which at first looks what you want), quorum (which is also an option), one and any. So let's assume you choose all, because you want to write to all replicas. That's totally fine, but if one of the nodes goes down, there will be failing writes, because one of the replicas could not be updated. In case you are actually using replication factor 3, you can fallback to write with quorum, which is 2 nodes in this case. What should happen if another node fails? I know, very unlikely, but I've seen it in production, so it happens from time to time. Should the single last node be updated in this case? Then you need to fallback to consistency level 1. Everything fine.

But what if you choose the replication factor to be 5? Well, there is no way of saying: I want 4 nodes. You can only have a quorum in case of a failure of one node, and that would be 3, not 4. And the next fallback would be 1 and not 2.

The final question is: if you lose one node and you do a fallbak in the writing part, what happens when your node comes back (assuming that there are lost updates because some of the hinted handoffs are already discarded)? The reading part of your application can always read stale data because you always only read from a single node. It seems to me like you are trying to compensate for that in the write part. My personal idea would be using quorum when reading and writing, this way it's guaranteed that you read current data and a single node can go down (with replication factor 5 it's even 2 nodes). Also keep in mind that when you write to a node, cassandra will always attempt to write to the replicas in the background, so it tries to keep your data up to date. The risk of reading stale data even with a consistency level pair of one-one can be acceptable if you really need the speed.